# Xamarin forms failing ti install NotificationHub Nuget in UWP project

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub, xamarin.uwp

Trying this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push, using VS 2017 portable Xamarin Forms project. Except UWP all other projects including IOS , Android and Portable library are getting installed with the Notificaiton nuget package. In UWP its always failing with the below error message. Thanks for your help.

**Package Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 1.0.9 is not compatible with uap10.0.10240 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) / win10-x86-aot. Package Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 1.0.9 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of July 2016 `Notification Hubs SDK` is not available for `UWP`. The product team is aware of it and working on providing it.

At the moment, there are one way to workaround it:

- Use `WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed` Nuget package as described in [Getting started with Notification Hubs for Windows Universal Platform Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification)

Certain Hubs SDKs are [open sourced](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs). But, unfortunately, not Windows ones at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, confused on the xamarin forms article. It says, Add push notifications to your Windows app
In Visual Studio, open App.xaml.cs in a Windows project, and add the following statements.

Copy
 using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
 using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;

Comment: yes, that is very confusing but remember that the notifications work independently according to each platform, so you can follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification) only for UWP platform. If this helped you please mark it as an answer :)